# disable browser bar buttons

Tags: sharepoint-online

i have several buttons near the New item button that user should not see. they just don´t need the option of automate, integrate power apps, bi ecc.

is there a way to disabile that?

i tried via the license option, with powershell but no result.
[image: browser bar buttons]

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to hide these buttons out-of-the-box. However, if you absolutely need to do it, you can create an **Application Customizers** using SharePoint framework. It does require development skills and is not straightforward for most people and organizations.

[Here is the documentation on SharePoint framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions) and **Application Customizers**